# Wordpress Site front End and Back End Loading Slowly

Tags: php, server

I have my personal [portfolio site](http://ujjwalrijal.com.np) which takes long time to load. After login to wp-admin, it takes longer time to open all the contents of site. I am surprised why this problem came to my site.

Also same problem in other site i have viewd also have same problem.

Also i tested the site in http://gtmetrix.com/ and it shows the less yslow speed and page speed.
Please give me the best solution to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using your own custom query then try to optimize them and use any compression and your site speed also depend on your hosting service please check your plan with hosting service provider to speed up your site performance.

Comment: no man, its wordpress default query. Hosting company alone may not create this problem.Site hosted with Best hosting company also suffter from this problem.

Comment: Wordpress is a resource hog. What version are you running? How many plugins? Have you optimized the installation?

Comment: To Speed up your website use the following plugins : [W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) [W3 Smush.it](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smushit/)

Comment: Any site can be a resource hog, WP can be very fast and lightweight. The plugin number performance is also a popular myth, 100 tiny lightweight plugins are faster than 1 large hulking plugin. To @Ujjwal I recommend you provide more information, perhaps through plugins such as debug bar or query monitor, and then rephrase your question to focus on the least performant aspect. As it stands your question is quite vague and open ended, there just isn't enough information to resolve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress is a great platform to develop web solutions. However if you consider following points then it would be much better.

- Reliable DNS
- Get your wordpress hosting right and use proper caching(WP Super
  Cache or W3 Total Cache)
- A clean theme and don't pile up with lots of plugins
- Disable trackbacks and pingbacks
- Move CSS to the top,JavaScript to the bottom  Use Content Delivery
  Networks (CDN)
- Use static page to show images, CSS, etc which prevents unnecessary
  data-such as cookie.
- Don't use Gravatar which adds weight to your page.
     Use CSS Image Sprites
- Remove unnecessary characters such as whitespace and comments
- Compressing your resources can greatly reduce the amount of data
  transferred between your server and the client.Services like Smush.it
  can compress image resources.
- Using gzipcompression for text based resources (HTML, CSS,
  JavaScript) can reduce sizes by 70%.
- Remove extra data such as revisions, trashed data and custom meta
  data.
- Avoid redirects. Add a RewriteRule or preferably a Redirect.
- Avoiding mod_rewrite. By default, WordPress uses RewriteRule to route
  requests to index.php.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

The front of your site is over 4mb big, you need to optimize images and code etc to get your page size down, and intern this will reduce your site load time.

[image: google network panel]